How can I add direction arrows on my google maps polyline in flutter
Example image
I have a flutter application that draws polylines on google map indicating the path of a user. I want to display the direction for the polyline using direction arrows similar to the direction arrows shown in the image which is of google maps. I am unable to figure it out.
I want to display these arrows on a certain zoom levels and also want them to increase or decrease as the zoom level changes exactly how it happens in google maps.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Add packages in your pubspec.yaml file:
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0

Fetch Polyline Points: Use the flutter_polyline_points package to fetch polyline points from the Google Directions API.
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

Future<List<LatLng>> getPolylinePoints() async {
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
  PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
    'YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY',
    PointLatLng(startLat, startLng),
    PointLatLng(endLat, endLng),
  );

  if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
    return result.points.map((point) => LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).toList();
  }
  return [];
}

Draw Polylines with Arrow:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  Set<Polyline> _polylines = {};
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setPolylines();
  }

  void _setPolylines() async {
    List<LatLng> polylinePoints = await getPolylinePoints();
    List<LatLng> arrowPoints = _getArrowPoints(polylinePoints);

    setState(() {
      _polylines.add(Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId('route'),
        points: polylinePoints,
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: 5,
      ));

      for (LatLng point in arrowPoints) {
        _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(point.toString()),
          position: point,
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
        ));
      }
    });
  }

  List<LatLng> _getArrowPoints(List<LatLng> polylinePoints) {
    // Logic to calculate arrow points based on polyline points
    // Add arrows at intervals or based on zoom level
    List<LatLng> arrowPoints = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < polylinePoints.length; i += 10) {
      arrowPoints.add(polylinePoints[i]);
    }
    return arrowPoints;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Polyline with Arrows')),
      body: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: (controller) => _controller = controller,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(startLat, startLng),
          zoom: 14.0,
        ),
        polylines: _polylines,
        markers: _markers,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Adjust Arrow Size Based on Zoom Level:
void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
  double zoom = position.zoom;
  // Adjust arrow size based on zoom level
  // Update markers with new size if necessary
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Polyline with Arrows')),
    body: GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: (controller) => _controller = controller,
      onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(startLat, startLng),
        zoom: 14.0,
      ),
      polylines: _polylines,
      markers: _markers,
    ),
  );
}

It may help you,

I have implemented a solution similar like this and it works fine, but I feels like it is not the right way to do it. There should be some sort of reliable and optimized solution for this.

okay, I will try to optimize the code.
